# I created one report with date parameters in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I created the report with date parameters like startdate and enddate (for 1 year list) and two more parameters sdate and edate (for 3 months list)
so now i got a requirement like
i need to display a drop down list like: 1 year and 3 months 
if i select 1 year , i have to see from current date to last year list ...

same for 3 months also and i created one more parameter duration in that parameter , i mentioned available values as 1 year and 3 months for drop down purpose.

so how this date parameters can reflects to that drop down list names ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how and what you have tried so far and you'll get help

Comment: You only need the one set of parameters for the dates and one other parameter which shows your dropdown list. One for start and one for end and one for list. You can then assign the values of the dropdown items to a sql dataset value that you can create which returns all the dates you would need. So the date for 1 year back and the date for 3 months back from today. You can then set your date parameters to be dependant on the dropdown list value and can grab the values from your dataset that you require.

Comment: hii ,,, i created drop down list by creating a parameter name as duration in that parameter , i name the list as 1 year and 3 months as default values ......how to assign drop down list to that start and end date parameters, which reflects the date parameters and  displays only that data which i selected from the drop down list

Comment: is it possible not to create any date parameters  . instead of that if i select drop down list it ill display the data

Comment: @rajendar Yes it is possible, you could just do a if statement in the query. You could just do a little iif() call in the where statement to say `where datesfield between iff(param = ..., 1yearbackdate, 3monthsbackdate ) and GETDATE()`

Comment: @rajendar The dropdown list value in the report that you click is what I am referring to as the parameter value / param in the above comment that you would reference in your sql query. If you add your current sql script to get your data at the moment to your question I can show you a proper example of how to use this.

Comment: @rajendar `WHERE MyDateField BETWEEN IIF(@ParamNameFromSSRS = 'Year', '20190101', '20190201') AND GETDATE()` This is pretty much all it would take, but you would need to get it to match up with your ssrs and sql fields and correct dates.

Comment: select sum(closeratio)/count(closeratio) as CloseRatio from (
select 
b.first_name+' '+ b.last_name 'Estimator', count(a.job_id) as closeratio
from [tenant1].[job_details] a
join [tenant1].user_user_details b
on a.estimator = b.user_id
where a.estimator is not null
and a.current_job_status in('Planning','Production','Invoice','Receivables','Closed')
and   a.job_type in('Reconstruction','Contents','Asbestos','Structure Cleaning')
--and a.job_type=('water')
--and a.created_datetime between  DATEADD(month, -12, @DATE) and @GETDATE())
group by b.first_name+' '+b.last_name ) a

Comment: THIS IS MY QUERY SO WHERE . I M HAVING 5 DATASET QUERY FOR ONE YEAR AND FOR 3 MONTHS WHERE CONDITIONS ARE DIFF. I CREATED ONE DATE PARAMETER

Comment: AND I CREATED TWO MORE PARAMETERS IN SSRS THAT  IS  , YEAR AND 3MONTHS. HOW TO ASSIGN